# A calculation involving Cotton tensor

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geometric-analysis

I have a confusion regarding a calculation given below :
$$
\begin{split}
\int_M C^{ij}\nabla_i f \nabla_j f d\mu & = \frac{1}{3}\int_M g^{ij}g_{ij} C^{ij}\nabla_i f \nabla_j f d\mu \\
&= \frac{1}{3}\int_M g_{ij}C^{ij}g^{ij}\nabla_i f \nabla_j f d\mu \\
&= \frac{1}{3}\int_M  g_{ij}C^{ij}|\nabla f|^2 d\mu =0
\end{split}
$$
since the Cotton tensor is traceless. This is done in dimensions three. I think this calculation is erroneous. Can we insert $g^{ij}g_{ij} $ inside?

Comment: In its current form the formulas are at best ambiguous. Perhaps you should write everything out explicitly without using any summation conventions.

Comment: In fact, you are misusing the summation convention.  You are using the $ij$-pair twice and then cross-binding them incorrectly.  The first term on the righthand side under the integral would be more correctly written as $g^{kl}g_{kl}C^{ij}\nabla_if\nabla_jf$, but then in the next line you using it as though it were $g^{kl}g_{ij}C^{ij}\nabla_kf\nabla_lf$, but it is clear that these two quantities are not at all the same.  Re-using indices that are already bound in a summation is a misuse of the summation convention, and it can easily lead (as it does here) to incorrect formulae.